# How to set default order for retrieving objects from parse?

Tags: parse-platform

I used rest api to retrieve objects from parse, I see objects return that are sorted default by `createdAt` column.

I wonder if i can change this default order in parse. It likes a predefined order. So I don't need to include param `"order=column_name"` in url.

I think with this predefined order, parse will return result faster than when I indicate order in url.

How to set default order for retrieving objects from parse?
Is there any way to setup default order in parse?

Comment: I think you can't change default order. what is the problem to include order param?

Comment: i just think that it will improve performance if i set predefined order in parse. If can't change, it's ok with param. Thank you for reply

Comment: https://www.parse.com/questions/what-is-the-default-order-of-queries
this post is by one of the parse developers. may be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot globally change the default sort order for a Parse table, however you can include the `order` param as you have mentioned. It should also be mentioned that you should not rely on the default sort order if the `order` parameter is omitted.

I have been using Parse with some very large datasets, and have not detected a performance penalty for using `order`.